# how to ping outside vpn tunnel to keep connection alive when using public wifi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn

I am using VPN (AirVPN) over public wifi (Mcdonald) i had to use an alternate port to be able to connect in the first place,
But now i get disconnected of wifi every 30 min or so (time out due to inactivity).
I thought of a solution which is to ping some website outside the tunnel, is that possible ? will it keep the connection alive? how to implement it ?

Comment: Are you sure it's due to inactivity? I would imagine that public wifi would have some sort of fixed expiration session timeout to try to disencourage abuse. Do you get disconnected after 30 min when not using the VPN?